# Android auto align icons in Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have 4 buttons (ImageView) in my top menu.
When i want to hide some buttons inside a fragment, they are not aligned to the right side, they just stand where they are (because of the margin i think) how can i change this code to make them align right? and have a margin to each other?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.PopupOverlay">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/help"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_help_outline_black_24dp"
                android:tint="@color/white"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/save"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_save_black_24dp"
                android:tint="@color/white"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/send"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="90dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp"
                android:tint="@color/white"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/preview"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="130dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_visibility_black_24dp"
                android:tint="@color/white"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main2" />
```

Comment: when you hide, set its visibility GONE.

Comment: yeah sure, thats not a problem, but when i hide them, there become gaps between the icons. but i want no gaps and just make them right aligned somehow.

Comment: try to set padding instead of margin to manage your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Put those icons in a menu file and add it to activity in onCreateOptionsMenu(menu).Try keeping the constant elements in the activity menu and the fragment dependent buttons/icons in fragment's menu and inflate it inside the fragment.Don't forget to call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)`
 in `onCreate` method of your fragment.To order the icons properly use `orderByCategory` property in the menu file

Answer (score 0):

@pila You can try this hope this can help you..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.PopupOverlay">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/help"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/help"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/send"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/save"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/preview"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/send"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

//<include layout="@layout/content_main2" />
```